# Pass extra data with Sinch VideoCalling

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

Here is code how i have implemented calling.

```
@Override
public void onClientStarted(SinchClient sinchClient) {
  Log.e(TAG, "started");

  callClient = sinchClient.getCallClient();
  callClient.addCallClientListener(this);
}
public void initiateCall(String receiverId) {
  Call call = callClient.callUserVideo(receiverId);
  call.addCallListener(this);
}
```

But i want to pass some data like username, profile image and other things, does there any way to pass those data with video calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution from sinch developer.

> You can pass along custom data providing headers to the
>   callUserVideo(String toUserId, Map headers) method. The headers you
>   pass can be retrieved from the incoming Call object using getHeaders()
>   method.
>   https://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/com/sinch/android/rtc/calling/Call.html

We can pass extra values in map when initializing call.

```
HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("userId","5");
map.put("profileImage","image url");

Call call = callClient.callUserVideo(receiverId,map);
```

Comment: Can we get these passing data from web app using javascript